# How to scrape specific content from Outlook with Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I'm building new business process, where I will retrieve all outlook emails with subject "Daily Summary" and "Trade Idea" content on the email. So far, I am only able to extract the body of the email. But, ideally, I would like to capture the "Trade Idea" content and store it into excel file along with the basic data of the email i.e. sender name and date of the email.

The "Trade Idea" paragraph is located at the end of the email, but there is basic email signature after that, how could I only retrieve the "Trade Idea" paragraph?

This is my code so far, which only prints the body of the email:

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")

inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 

message=inbox.Items
message2=message.GetLast()
subject=message2.Subject
body=message2.body
date=message2.senton.date()
sender=message2.Sender
attachments=message2.Attachments


for m in message:
    if 'Daily Summary' in m.Subject :
        print(m.body)
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
      Date      Sender      Trade Idea
      1-Jul-19  John Doe    Buying ABC stock, selling DEF stock
```

Answer (score 1):

> all outlook emails with subject "Daily Summary" and "Trade Idea"

To get items that correspond to your conditions you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class, read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also, you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Outlook Application class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, **you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body**.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi @Eugene, thanks for the elaborate reply. However, I don't have any programming background and very new to Python as well. Would you mind give an example how could I implement the code? Thanks!

Comment: SO is for developers, so I'd recommend learning basics at least. It is definitely not a service for requesting and getting a solution out of the box.